# Running db2relocatedb with ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, db2

I have this ansible playbook:

```
 ---
 - hosts: all
   gather_facts: False
   become: yes
   become_user: myins
   become_method: sudo

   tasks:

     - name: test someting
       command: "cd /db2/myins"

     - name: relocate it 
       command: "db2relocatedb -f /db2/myins/relocate.cfg"

 ...
```

if I run the command by itself it works and if I use cat /db2/myins/relocate.cfg instead of db2relocatedb -f it works too.

If I run it like this I get:

```
 The full traceback is:
 WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
 File "/tmp/ansible_command_payload_HGHkvR/ansible_command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2561, in run_command
cmd = subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception

fatal: [mounttest]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"cmd": "db2relocatedb -f /db2/myins/relocate.cfg",
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "_raw_params": "db2relocatedb -f /db2/myins/relocate.cfg",
        "_uses_shell": false,
        "argv": null,
        "chdir": null,
        "creates": null,
        "executable": null,
        "removes": null,
        "stdin": null,
        "stdin_add_newline": true,
        "strip_empty_ends": true,
        "warn": true
    }
},
"msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory",
"rc": 2
 }
```

Why can I cat the file but not use it?

Thanks,
Arengin

Comment: mytestuser, but I use become to change into the correct user

Comment: I have centOS and run ansible2.8.0 the cmd is on PATH since I can run it everywhere on the machine when I am logged onto it. I now changed the yml to copy the file to the irectory and then use it. It does copy it and then says "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory",
    "rc": 2

Comment: Your comment says db2relocatedb runs OK at the shell as `mytestuser`, but your question has `become_user: myins` .

Comment: it may be that ansible might not run the shell startup script(s) on which db2relocatedb may depend, and ansible may use a different $PWD.  You can run ansible with the -vvv option to give more details of locations.

Comment: ok solved it.. for some reason the command needed a "cd folder && db2relocate..." even a cd before was not enough

Answer (score -1):

the problem is inside relocate.cfg, check all Pathes make sure they are full qualified, make sure no escape character is somewhere

Comment: The answer is imprecise. If you think the source of problem is in a file not previewed by the question ask for more information in a comment and then point to it clearly.